# TextView goes behind the button in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

I have a RelativeLayout where I have a TextView and a Button. Button has an attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, it's ok. The problem is a TextView: if the text is large, it goes behind the button.

[RelativeLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nonpx.png)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:text="Long long string"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#d9e700"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I need is resizable TextView which won't get behind the button. If the text is large, we can see only that part of text which fits the size between the top and the button.
Something like two lines where line #2 (with button) has fixed height, and the line #1 is resizable.
Does someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
```

to your TextView like:

```
<RelativeLayout android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:text="Long long string"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#d9e700"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just one line, OMG... 
Thank you very much, it's really solved my problem!

Comment: Working in api 18.  There is no layout_above option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to align the text view above button . Use **layout_above** attribute.
 Below is an example.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:minWidth="25px">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp"
    android:text="Long long string"
    android:textColor="#d9e700"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add android:layout_above="@id/button1" in your textview
2) Put your textview below your button so you can give refrence of button to your textview.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12.5dp"
        android:text="Long long string"
        android:textColor="#d9e700"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!